Unable to get driver to connect to MariaDB
I have recently begun making a plugin for a Minecraft server of mine and need to use a database for persistent storage. As such I am now trying to use the MariaDB server on the machine (which I can use just fine from the terminal) to store the information I need which I am having troubles connecting to.
Minimizing the code to the part throwing the exception, my snippet looks like this.
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public final class Extrelco extends JavaPlugin {
    // This function will be called by the server once at startup
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/databasename", "username", "password"
        );
    }
}

The exception I get is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver which I already tried looking up. This question even had the same problem as I do, but OP simply didn't add the driver to the CLASSPATH which I have already done using manual dependency management in IntelliJ Idea according to this question.
I also tried adding the driver as a dependency using Gradle according to the site I got the JAR from, which prompted me to simply add implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:4.2' to my build.gradle. This also resulted in the same issue.
I've also read that the Class.forName() call is the "legacy way of registering the driver" (comment on the top answer on this question) according to which I have tried simply removing the call. That gave me a different exception, now stating that java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for... (my getConnectionCall above).
By now I'm just absolutely clueless as to what is causing this.

It is wrong to use "implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:4.2'" , because there is no 4.2 above. You can find 3.4.1 on the mvnrepository site ( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/3.4.1 ) "implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.4.1'"

@life888888 This successfully added the dependency via Gradle but did not solve the problem. Thank you nevertheless, I've confused the version with the one on the homepage of package.

Make sure you have synchronized your gradle build file in IDEA. Check that the library is shown in the Project tab to the left of the editing window, under the "External Libraries" tree. Maybe you need to rebuild the project.

@k314159 I have, thats how I found out that only now Gradle added the dependency. Concerning the rebuild, IntelliJ Idea has a lint that wont let me build since it already knows the call will throw. I even used auto completion to reference the class.

Try building using Gradle on the command line: ./gradlew build

@k314159 error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. Seemed to be Gradle itself, not Idea's lint.

Just add a throws ClassNotFoundException on the declaration of your method: public void onEnable() throws ClassNotFoundException {

Im terribly sorry I forgot to add the @Override annotation. I edited the question. This annotation prevents me from doing so.

You can surround your statements with try { ...your statements here... } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); } - that will make the unreported exception error go away.

@k314159 How does that solve the problem? I still need to load the driver. Without it, the plugin isnt of much use.

It will allow you to build the application. You said you are currently getting an unreported exception error which is preventing you from compiling the code. I believe you already have the driver in your classpath, you just need to be able to build your application.

@k314159 I built the project and it throws and exception upon executing the function loading the plugin. The server simply disables my plugin.

what if you just import the class?

@ErikKaplun Just tested it, importing org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver changes nothing

This is not a smart answer, but it works in my environment (minecraft forge).
The Easy Way: Download Mariadb Minecraft Mod, if you are using Minecraft Forge.
https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/search?page=1&pageSize=20&sortBy=relevancy&search=mariadb
search: input mariadb
find one: MariaDB JDBC (Fabric/Forge)
https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mariadb-jdbc
Click download.

Please adjust the version according to your environment.
download mariadb-jdbc-2.7.4+20211227-all.jar
copy mariadb-jdbc-2.7.4+20211227-all.jar into ~/.minecraft/mods
My Test Project:
Download forge-1.21-51.0.33-mdk.zip
Unzip
build.gradle
add implementation('org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.4.1') in  dependencies block
dependencies {
...
    implementation('org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.4.1')
}    

ExampleMod.java
Add
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

In class ClientModEvents, add some jdbc code for test:
    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically register all static methods in the class annotated with @SubscribeEvent
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = MODID, bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD, value = Dist.CLIENT)
    public static class ClientModEvents
    {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onClientSetup(FMLClientSetupEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println(">>>>**** HELLO FROM CLIENT SETUP");//no output
            System.out.println(">>>>**** MINECRAFT NAME >> " + Minecraft.getInstance().getUser().getName());//no output
            // Some client setup code
            LOGGER.info(">>>> HELLO FROM CLIENT SETUP");
            LOGGER.info(">>>> MINECRAFT NAME >> {}", Minecraft.getInstance().getUser().getName());

            try {
                Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
                LOGGER.info(">>>> OK org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                LOGGER.info(">>>> driver not found :" +  e.getMessage());
            }



            // JDBC URL format: jdbc:mariadb://<host>:<port>/<database>
            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://192.168.56.101:3306/demodb";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "rootPassword";

            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                // 1. Establish connection to the database
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                LOGGER.info(">>>> conn OK");
                // 2. Create statement
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                LOGGER.info(">>>> stmt OK");
                // 3. Execute query
                String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                LOGGER.info(">>>> rs OK");
                // 4. Process the result set
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt("id");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    int age = rs.getInt("age");
                    String grade = rs.getString("grade");

                    LOGGER.info("ID: " + id + ", Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age + ", Grade: " + grade);

                }
                LOGGER.info(">>>> end while");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                LOGGER.info(">>>> Exception: "+ e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                // 5. Close resources
                try {
                    if (rs != null) rs.close();
                    if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
                    if (conn != null) conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    LOGGER.info(">>>> Exception 2: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info(">>>> end onClientSetup method");
        } //onClientSetup
    } // class ClientModEvents    

build
gradle clean build


JDK 21
Gradle 8.10

Copy it to mods directory
copy build/libs/examplemod-1.0.0.jar into ~/.minecraft/mods
start minecraft Launcher
do something.
then check logs : ~/.minecraft/logs/latest.log
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> HELLO FROM CLIENT SETUP
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> MINECRAFT NAME >> userXXXXX
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> OK org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> conn OK
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> stmt OK
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> rs OK
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: ID: 1, Name: MARIADB Alice, Age: 20, Grade: A
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: ID: 2, Name: MARIADB Bob, Age: 22, Grade: B
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: ID: 3, Name: MARIADB Charlie, Age: 21, Grade: A
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: ID: 4, Name: MARIADB David, Age: 23, Grade: C
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: ID: 5, Name: MARIADB Eva, Age: 20, Grade: B
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> end while
[18:11:24] [Worker-Main-6/INFO]: >>>> end onClientSetup method


Gradle doesn't download to the .m2 directory. Substitute .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ for .m2/repository/. Also, for dependency tree, use ./gradlew dependencies (or ./gradlew app:dependencies depending on your directory structure).

The problem could not be directly solved at this moment, was however averted using ObjectOutputStream.
I'm simply writing all the data containers to their own file when the server shuts down
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
    "plugins/MyPlugin/data/some_data.bin"));
oos.writeObject(myObjectContainingAllTheData);
oos.close();

... and read them back in when starting again.
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream( 
    "plugins/MyPlugin/data/some_data.bin"));
myObjectContainingAllTheData = (HashMap<UUID, SomeSerializableType>)ois.readObject();
ois.close();

(try-catch left out for simplicity)
